# Cooking Turkey Legs and boneless Turkey breast in an electric roaster

Tags: equipment

Just two people for Thanksgiving.  One wants to eat healthy (I bought a boneless Turkey Breast at Whole Foods) and the other wants Turkey legs (also from Whole Foods).  My oven is broken so I just purchased an electric roaster but have never used one and am new to cooking in general.  I'd appreciate any guidance in terms of how to use the electric roaster to cook both these items.  There is plenty of information out there on how to good an entire Turkey in an electric roaster, but not just parts.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use a probe thermometer.  Cook the turkey breast to 160F.  Roast the leg/thigh until the temp reaches 180F.  Make sure the thermometer is not touching bone. The legs are more forgiving and won't dry out as readily. So, you might want to start the legs 40 minutes or so before the breast so that they are done around the same time.